# Django MySQL fail to get the last state of my db

Tags: python, mysql, django

I’m currently working on a Django 1.11 project where I have two models Profile and Campaign, the first one inlines the second.
I want to apply a asynchronous function when I save my Profile. So to do that I create a celery task.

```
# in admin.py
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # some stuff

 def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        print(“before save: ” + str(len(campaigns)))
        super(type(self), self).save_related(request, form, fomsets, change)
        campaigns = Campaign.objects.filter(is_enabled=True)
        print(“after save: ” + str(len(campaigns)))
        tasks.foo.delay()

# in tasks.py
@shared_task
def foo():
    campaigns = Campaign.objects.filter(is_enabled=True)
    print(“Foo: ” + str(len(campaigns)))
```

My issue is that the length of the campaigns in foo is the length print before the save and not after. This issue disappear when I add a sleep at the beginning of foo.

Example output:

```
before save: 5
after save: 3
Foo: 5
```

This issue exist only on my google instance with mysql 5.7.

I don’t understand why the campaign is not always correct in foo.
I doesn’t find any reason to explain this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `save_related()` is called inside a transaction. This means that it's possible for `foo()` to run inside a worker process before the transaction in the main process is complete. This will result in the behavior you've observed where the task (which is outside of the transaction) will not see the changes to the database.

It's a race condition and may not always happen. It may be more likely on some machines than others.

One easy fix would be to add a countdown to the task:

```
tasks.foo.delay(countdown=1)
```